# kivy: popup with progress bar

Tags: python, popup, progress-bar, kivy

Is it possible to create a popup with a "moving" progressbar?

Here is an example of what I tried, but it'll only display the popup after the the loop is complete. I'd like to have it visible while doing it.

```
import time

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

databases = range(5)

class testApp(App):

    def launch_popup(self, instance):
        print("Button pressed for popup: {0}".format(instance))
        import time 

        pb = ProgressBar() #100
        popup = Popup(title='Syncing Databases', content=pb, size_hint=(0.7, 0.3))
        popup.open()

        for i in databases:
            time.sleep(1) #simulate syncing database
            pb.value += 100/len(databases)
            print("Progressbar is on {0}%".format(pb.value))


    def build(self):
        btn = Button(text="Popup", on_press=self.launch_popup)
        return btn


testApp().run()
```

Or should I use threads/a custom widget, if so how would I implement that?

Many thanks already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the for loop blocks not just the popup, but *everything* else in your app - it runs in the same thread as kivy's eventloop, so kivy can't do anything at all until it's finished.

You should instead run your for loop in a separate thread or break it up into smaller components that can be scheduled with Clock.schedule_once or Clock.schedule_interval. This will let kivy perform its normal tasks in between running the bits of your code.